# SlingFilter does not catch Exceptions?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, aem, sling

I am implementing a Authentication Filter and I am also using it for exception handling.
As there is no web.xml in CQ5 so we can't put a mapping like  `<exception-type>`.

All my controllers(Servlets) throw Exception back to caller. And I have a filter that is called before each and every one of my Servlets. So I am explicitly throwing

```
new SerlvetException()
```

in one of my servlets. This is ofcourse thrown to the caller i.e my main filter. Exception occurs correctly at `chain.doFilter()` and I am handling the exception here(in filter). but it just doesn't get handled why?
**Also,what is this Scope property SlingFilter I dont understand this REQUEST,ERROR, COMPONENT,INCLUDE property of SlingFilter SCOPE**

Here is my code and stack trace.

```
public class AddNewUserController extends SlingAllMethodsServlet{

    /**
     * @author Oliver Kaunds
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());



    @Reference
    protected AddNewUserService addNewUserService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {


        log.info("VideoJet :: Do GET Called ");
        String path =request.getRequestURI();
        log.info("VIDEOJET PATH :: "+ path);
        try{
            if(path.equals("/services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view"))
            {


                List<HRRepresentative> list =addNewUserService.getHRRepresentative();
                request.setAttribute("hrList",list );
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                String userOperation =(String)session.getAttribute("userOp");
                request.setAttribute("userOp", userOperation);
                session.removeAttribute("userOp");
                throw new Exception("Error Page Test"); // Manuly throw exception

            }
```

And my main filter

```
package com.videojet.hiresite.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingFilter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;



@SlingFilter(order=1)

@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.pid", value="com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter",propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="service.description",value="Main Authentication Filter", propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="service.vendor",value="Zensar Tech", propertyPrivate=false),
    @Property(name="pattern",value="/services/videojet/v1/.*", propertyPrivate=false)   
})
public class HireSiteFilter implements Filter {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Authentication Filter for the whole application
        log.info("HireSiteFilter Invoked");

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        String path =httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
        log.info("Request URI on AJAX ::"+path);
        try{


            if(path.contains("LoginController"))
            {
                log.info("HireSiteFilter :: Request to LoginController");
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
                if(session ==null || session.getAttribute("userId")==null)
                {
                    log.info("HireSiteFilter :: Not Logged in");
                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
                    httpResponse.sendRedirect("/content/videojet/en/loginPage.html");
                }
                else
                {
                    log.info("HireSiteFilter :: Logged in");
                    chain.doFilter(request, response); // This is within Try block---!!!!!!!!!!
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // Internal Server Error Manul dispatch to Error Page
            // /content/videojet/en/errorPage.html
            log.info("********************* TEST ***********************************");
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse =(HttpServletResponse)response;
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/content/videojet/en/errorPage.html");


        }



    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

the Exception occurs correct but is not caught by the catch block. the stack trace is below.

```
04.07.2014 11:46:26.395 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586395] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter HireSiteFilter Invoked
04.07.2014 11:46:26.395 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586395] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter Request URI on AJAX ::/services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser
04.07.2014 11:46:26.395 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586395] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter HireSiteFilter :: Request to LoginController
04.07.2014 11:46:26.399 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.LoginController Do Post **************
04.07.2014 11:46:26.399 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.LoginController The Username :::::foster
04.07.2014 11:46:26.399 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.LoginController The Password ::::::test
04.07.2014 11:46:26.399 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.daos.EmployeeDaoImp JCR QUERY 1::SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE  ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/videojetdata/HR_EMPLOYEE') AND NAME(s) = 'foster'
04.07.2014 11:46:26.864 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.daos.EmployeeDaoImp Query Check :: Presenttest
04.07.2014 11:46:26.866 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.services.login.LoginServiceImp The Passwrod from the daatabase+++++++test**********
04.07.2014 11:46:26.866 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.LoginController Username::foster
04.07.2014 11:46:26.866 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.LoginController Password::test
04.07.2014 11:46:26.869 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586398] POST /services/videojet/v1/LoginController/validateUser HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.daos.EmployeeDaoImp JCR Query::SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE  ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/videojetdata/HR_EMPLOYEE') AND NAME(s) = 'foster'
04.07.2014 11:46:26.943 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586943] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter HireSiteFilter Invoked
04.07.2014 11:46:26.943 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586943] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter Request URI on AJAX ::/services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view
04.07.2014 11:46:26.943 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586943] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter HireSiteFilter :: Logged in
04.07.2014 11:46:26.945 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.AddNewUserController VideoJet :: Do GET Called 
04.07.2014 11:46:26.945 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.AddNewUserController VIDEOJET PATH :: /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view
04.07.2014 11:46:26.945 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.daos.HRRepresentativeDaoImp THE JCR QUERY ::SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE  ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/videojetdata/HR_REP')
04.07.2014 11:46:27.740 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DocNumberCache size=715/1024, #accesses=1001, #hits=256, #misses=745, cacheRatio=26%
04.07.2014 11:46:29.642 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-24-com/day/cq/replication/job/publish(com/day/cq/replication/job/publish)] com.day.cq.replication.impl.AgentManagerImpl Processing job for agent publish
04.07.2014 11:46:29.643 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-24-com/day/cq/replication/job/publish(com/day/cq/replication/job/publish)] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish Sending POST request to http://localhost:4503/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1
04.07.2014 11:46:29.893 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DocNumberCache size=121/1024, #accesses=1001, #hits=520, #misses=481, cacheRatio=52%
04.07.2014 11:46:30.604 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1404454586944] GET /services/videojet/v1/AddNewUserController/view HTTP/1.1] com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.AddNewUserController VIDEJET EXCEPTION:: java.lang.Exception: Error Page Test
    at com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.AddNewUserController.doGet(com.videojet.hiresite.controllers.AddNewUserController.java:75)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:139)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:308)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:296)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:220)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter.doFilter(com.videojet.hiresite.filters.HireSiteFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:315)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:334)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:377)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:625)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source
```

Comment: What types of exceptions have you handled at the slingFilter? Probably a different exception as the ServletException is handled. That could cause the issue. Its easy to try with handling the java.lang.Exception.

Comment: In catch block I have used java.lang.Exception `catch(Exception e)`

Answer (score 1):

Sling filter scopes are explained at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html

Comment: Yess I dont' understand them... I've read that. can you please explain that to me?

Answer (score 1):

Try using scope as 
@SlingFilter(scope = SlingFilterScope.COMPONENT, order = -10000, metatype = 
false) 
I think in your case it should be SlingFilterScope.ERROR

sling.filter.scope – Indicates the filter chain the filter should 
be part of. Required! Sling won’t pick up your filter if it isn’t 
set.

Also, Check Filterconditions at first place like shown below

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest pRequest, ServletResponse pResponse, 
FilterChain pChain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
if (!(pRequest instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest)) { 
 throw new ServletException("Request is not a Sling HTTP request."); 
 } 
 if (isFilterEnabled(slingRequest)) { 
 // Implement Filter-Logic 
 } else { 
 // continue with filter chaining 
 pChain.doFilter(pRequest, pResponse); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What servlet Filter can be used for ?
 1. Authentication blocking request based on user identity
 2. Logging and auditing - Tracking uses of a web application
 3. Image conversion - Scaling maps and so on 
 4. Data Compression - Making downloads smaller
 5. Localization - Targeting a request and response in particular locale
 6. XSL/T Transformation of XML content

I am not sure but i think it doesn't support exception handling. Do check once.